# Angular Flex - media.isActive() and media Observable alternative

Tags: angular, media-queries

Right now, I'm using `@angular/flex-layout` to do calculations based on breakpoints.

I have a sample code below so you could see the extent of how I use `@angular/flex` but nothing more. Just a checker of breakpoints:

```
private mediaChange(): void {
  this.media.asObservable().subscribe(
    (media) => {
      media.mqAlias !== FOO_BREAKPOINT
        ? // Do this
        : // or do that
    }
  );
}
```

Due to some browser support, dropped the use of `@angular/flex-layout` and tried to look for other option but fail to find one that I'm thinking on using regular media queries instead.

Are there any other option before jumping to media queries?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Observable
  .fromEvent(window, 'resize')
  .startWith(null)
  .subscribe(() => 
    console.log(window.innerWidth);
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

@angular/flex-layout doesn't gives support to old versions of Angular, are you using Angular 6,7 or 8? It should work on that versions.
For example Flex Layout library doesn't support Angular 4

The alternative is Angular CDK.
https://alligator.io/angular/breakpoints-angular-cdk/